# Shell script works fine from shell but doesn’t work as expected when executed via PHP “shell_exec” code

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4, shell-exec

This record.sh script shell is here and works fine on command line to record an MP4 file from a local flv live stream:

```
DATE=`date +"%d-%m-%Y-%T"`
if [ -s NAMESTREAM ]
then
cat config.php | dos2unix | grep auth | grep username | \
awk -F ' ' '{print $3}' | sed "s/'//g" | sed "s/;//g" | while read VAR
do echo $VAR > RECSTREAM
echo "Starting recording ..."
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://localhost/hls/$VAR" -crf 19 videos/"$VAR"_"$DATE".mp4
done
else
echo "Streaming is not started, please start it before"
fi
```

I send a shell_exec to call the last shell script in a php script like this:

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('/usr/local/nginx/html/mydir');
$output = shell_exec('nohup ./record.sh >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
chdir($old_path);
```

The MP4 video files are generated but unreadable with VLC, etc… It seems that the problem is due to my PHP script but I am not able to know why.

When executing from the shell command line: PHP myphpscript.php works fine, MP4 video files are OK. But from the PHP web page, the MP4 video files are corrupted.

Any ideas? Any param to test in FFmpeg to have a good mp4 video file?

Comment: How do you check that the videos are corrupted? Please show the ffmpeg log created when running the command.

Comment: Also, discarding output isn't helpful either. Further, you didn't explain how you call the code. Remember that user permissions might be important and those change significantly when using a webserver.

Comment: hi,Thanks for u to help me. One ffmpeg -i file.mp4 gives me this error: [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55dce3663820] moov atom not found
VIDEO.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input. This is not the case when i run the php or shell script from command line. This happens only when executing the scripts from php web site. I have in one page: two buttons, one start the record stream and one other stop the recording. Stopping the recording with one kill -9 PID command (php shell_exec -> shell script) gives me this corrupt file. I don't find any solution for the moment. Thanks for any idea.

Comment: i add to my last message that recording an avi file from the live rtmp ffmpeg command works fine. Problem is really mp4 format that is broken when killing the rtmp live recording with kill -9 PID ....

Comment: hi guys, i saw in the forum someone who gets the same problem of corrupted mp4 video file when sendind a kill -9 PID to the ffmpeg command : see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529348/how-to-programmatically-start-stop-ffmpeg-stream-transcoding/59255136#59255136 . So the solution as whished, is to send a 'q' command to the ffmpeg process to terminates itself normally. Do you know how to do this with php ? shell script ? something else ? Thanks in advance. eric.

Comment: hi, i found a solution send a SIGQUIT signal to the background process to terminate the ffmpeg command normally, just use kill -s QUIT $PID and the process will finish with a nice, so nice MP4 video file not corrupted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically start/stop FFMPEG stream transcoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529348/how-to-programmatically-start-stop-ffmpeg-stream-transcoding)

Comment: @EricFeillant Unrelated to this question, but dunno how to contact you otherwise. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522713/creating-a-tennis-scoring-system-in-php. Feel free to remove this comment or answer me so I can remove this comment when you've seen it.