# Creating a tennis scoring system in php

Tags: php

*I was in the process of answering the question below when it got closed. I flagged it for reopen more than an hour ago, but the moderators seem on holiday, so here is the question again, with answer this time. It was suggested to me by a moderator of another StackExchange community, that this was best practice.*

Originally posted by Eric Feillant:

I start in php and need your suggestions because my small script does not work as i would like.

```
$newpoints1p = $points1p['p1_points_score']; //<-- get it from one MySQL select request.
$AD='AD';


if (isset($_POST['p1poplus']))
{
        if ($newpoints1p <= 15 )
        {
                $newpoints1p += 15;  //<-- increment 15 OK
                }
                else if ($newpoints1p == 30 && $newpoints1p <= 40) { $newpoints1p += 10; }   //<-- incrément 10 OK
            else if ($newpoints1p <= 50) {$newpoints1p = $AD;}   //<-- display AD OK
            else $newpoints1p = 0;  //<-- Here is the pb, Display 15 as we attempt to have zéro ? because of (AD) string ?

 /* Will have the same trouble to décrémentbecause of 'AD' ? */
                   }  if(isset($_POST['p1pomoins']))
{
 if ($newpoints1p >= 40)
    {
            $newpoints1p -= 10;
            }
            else if ($newpoints1p <= 30 && $newpoints1p > 0) { $newpoints1p -= 15; }
 }
```

Comment: @EricFeillant I reposted your question with answer, because it got closed too quickly. Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I looked over your script, but it does things way more complicated than it has to be, so I decided to rewrite it rather than to solve where things go wrong. The following code will succesfully do what you want it to do.

```
<?php
// The points you get from the database
$sPoints = "0";

// An array with all the possible scores, with the beginning value at the end for looping
$aPoints = array("0", "15", "30", "40", "AD", "0");

// Find the index in the array
$iPoint_index = array_search ($sPoints, $aPoints);

// Get the index of the next item
$iPoint_index++;

// Return the value of the next item
$sPoints = $aPoints[$iPoint_index];

// display this on the page.
echo $sPoints;
```